Pasting code in python console in QGIS, recognize line change
I'm trying to simply paste Python code I have in a text file to the QGIS Python console.
While this worked before, I'm now receiving this error:
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
For instance, if I copy this:
import processing
from qgis.core import *
It fails, but if I copy each line individually, it works.
From what I understand, the console doesn't recognize the line change in my pasted code, and thinks all my lines are following each other.
I've tried to force a newline character, but this doesn't work.
I've seen user solve a similar issue with this line, but I can't get it to work in a Windows 11 environment.
echo "set enable-bracketed-paste off" >> ~/.inputrc
EDIT:
I just tested this in QGIS 3.28 and I don't have the problem. In 3.38 and above, I have it (didn't test versions in between)

Do you really need this? Why not use the script editor instead?

I suggest you to create an issue report at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues.

In the little toolbar above the python console, click the "Show editor" button and paste your code in the editor.

Thank you. While the Script editor is indeed a better tool that I'll start to use more, I'd still want to understand why this can no longer be done in the regular console. As @AndreaGiudiceandrea suggested, I'll report the issue.
